# Proper way to add Bootstrap and font-awesome CDNs to Theme (Magento 2.3.5)

Tags: magento-community, magento2.3.5

I am trying to add these CDNs to my custom theme: **`app\design\frontend\Magento\test\Magento_Theme\layout\default_head_blocks.xml`** file but it's not working, error : `failed to load resource`.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

It says: `Refused to load the script` **'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js'**

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

To add external static resources like CSS, JavaScript, Web fonts (Fontawesome in this case), Please follow the steps below.

1. Go to this [link](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use) and copy the CDN URL of Fontawesome.
2. Find the file `app/design/frontend/{Themevendor}/{Themename}/Magento_Theme/layout/default_head_blocks.xml` and paste the line below. (The line should be placed in the `head` tag and the value of `src_type` should be `url`.)

`<css src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.2.0/css/all.css" src_type="url"/>`

For details please visit this Magento 2 devdocs [link](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-manage.html)

Comment: Also you can watch this video for better understanding: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jJfVUS2aMNI&ab_channel=Pagayo

Comment: bro i dont want it to use as a cdn, i want to download the resource and use it as a dependency.

Comment: the answer you have given already available.

Comment: its saying Refused to load the script 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js'

Comment: did watch video as I mentioned above cuz it's using downloaded resource.

Answer (score 0):

For local and external resources, includes are slightly different, note the `src_type` attribute for external resources.

CSS, Script and other type (link) mentioned here, usually  and  tags should be sufficient.

```
<!-- Add local resources -->
    <css src="css/my-styles.css"/>
    <!-- The following two ways to add local JavaScript files are equal -->
    <script src="Magento_Catalog::js/sample1.js"/>
    <link src="js/sample.js"/>
    
<!-- Add external resources -->
    <css src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css"
src_type="url" />
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js" 
src_type="url" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" src="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" 
src_type="url" />
```